# How to create two tables with first 75% and remaining 25% of another table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this expecting it would work but `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` doesn't allow me do any calculations by giving error : "Error Code: 1327. Undeclared variable: ceil
"

```
INSERT INTO as24t
SELECT * FROM as24 LIMIT ceil(count(*)*3/4);
INSERT INTO as24v
SELECT * FROM as24 LIMIT floor(count(*)/4) OFFSET ceil(count(*)*3/4);
```

All I want to do is take first 3/4 of as24 table and insert into as24t and remaining 1/4 to as24v, considering some tables have odd number of records. Also, I don't want to calculate it and hardcode numbers into query because I have 40+ tables to divide and I feel there must be a clever way.

Comment: can you try with CEIL, maybe case sensitivity here is an issue and so you are getting this error.

Comment: I forgot to mention rows were ordered by a timestamp column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find something unique to order by in order to verify that you get complement sets.

```
set @numrows_25=(select count(*) from as24) * 0.25;

PREPARE STMT FROM 'INSERT INTO as24v SELECT * FROM as24 order by ... LIMIT ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @numrows_25;

PREPARE STMT FROM 'INSERT INTO as24t SELECT * FROM as24 order by ... LIMIT 9999999999 OFFSET ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @numrows_25;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I modified it a little bit and it worked just perfectly.

Comment: set @lim1=ceil((select count(*) from as24) * 0.75);
set @lim2=floor((select count(*) from as24) * 0.25);
PREPARE STMT FROM 'INSERT INTO as24t SELECT * FROM as24 LIMIT ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @lim1;
PREPARE STMT FROM 'INSERT INTO as24v SELECT * FROM as24 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @lim2, @lim1;